# How do I reset GitHub Copilot extension in Visual Studio 2022? (Not Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

My GitHub Copilot extension keeps saying I am not signed in even though I have signed in to GitHub. Here is a screenshot.

I have tried uninstalling/installing the extension, even logging out and logging in back to GitHub, nothing works.

Unfortunately, **there's no option to reset the extension from Visual Studio UI**.

[image: GitHub Copilot Agent - NotSignedIn]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind..., I have **nuked** my Visual Studio settings effectively resetting everything to default and then reinstall the Copilot extension.

I followed the guide here to reset my Visual Studio extension setting : http://www.michalsakowicz.com/2018/05/26/visual-studio-extensions-issues.html

**Option 4, Reset all settings in Visual Studio**

Delete folders `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_???????` (where question marks are some random instance characters.)

After that Visual Studio settings will be reset and I reinstall all my extensions from scratch.